# R strange result when converting from zoo object to tseries

Tags: r, time-series, zoo

I am getting strange results when I convert a regular zoo object to tseries.  I have tried this on two different versions of R (3.2.2 and 3.0.0) and two versions of zoo (1.7-12 and 1.7-11) on different computers with different OS (Windows 7 x64 SP1 and Centos 7.0) with the same outcome.

Simply I create a regular zoo object using data from a csv file which looks like this:

```
dput(x0)
structure(list(MonthDate = structure(1:43, .Label = c("2012-01", 
"2012-02", "2012-03", "2012-04", "2012-05", "2012-06", "2012-07", 
"2012-08", "2012-09", "2012-10", "2012-11", "2012-12", "2013-01", 
"2013-02", "2013-03", "2013-04", "2013-05", "2013-06", "2013-07", 
"2013-08", "2013-09", "2013-10", "2013-11", "2013-12", "2014-01", 
"2014-02", "2014-03", "2014-04", "2014-05", "2014-06", "2014-07", 
"2014-08", "2014-09", "2014-10", "2014-11", "2014-12", "2015-01", 
"2015-02", "2015-03", "2015-04", "2015-05", "2015-06", "2015-07"
), class = "factor"), Qty = c("88", "103", "120", "74", "83", 
"65", "72", "68", "64", "80", "53", "70", "49", "43", "58", "63", 
"63", "57", "70", "64", "56", "66", "64", "68", "48", "51", "57", 
"56", "52", "60", "56", "54", "43", "63", "47", "65", "42", "41", 
"52", "68", "57", "0", "0")), .Names = c("MonthDate", "Qty"), row.names = c(NA, 43L), class = "data.frame")
```

I then create a zoo object and convert it to a regular one in case the data has any missing values

```
x0.zoo <- zoo(x0[,2], order.by=x0[,1])
x0.reg <- aggregate(x0.zoo, as.yearmon, identity)
is.regular(x0.reg)
[1] TRUE
```

Which gives me:

```
x0.reg
Jan 2012 Feb 2012 Mar 2012 Apr 2012 May 2012 Jun 2012 Jul 2012 Aug 2012 Sep 2012 Oct 2012 Nov 2012 
  88      103      120       74       83       65       72       68       64       80       53 
Dec 2012 Jan 2013 Feb 2013 Mar 2013 Apr 2013 May 2013 Jun 2013 Jul 2013 Aug 2013 Sep 2013 Oct 2013 
  70       49       43       58       63       63       57       70       64       56       66 
Nov 2013 Dec 2013 Jan 2014 Feb 2014 Mar 2014 Apr 2014 May 2014 Jun 2014 Jul 2014 Aug 2014 Sep 2014 
  64       68       48       51       57       56       52       60       56       54       43 
Oct 2014 Nov 2014 Dec 2014 Jan 2015 Feb 2015 Mar 2015 Apr 2015 May 2015 Jun 2015 Jul 2015 
  63       47       65       42       41       52       68       57        0        0
```

Then if I convert this to a tseries the data values completely change:

```
as.ts(x0.reg)
     Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
2012  28   2   3  25  27  20  24  22  19  26  12  23
2013   9   6  16  18  18  15  23  19  14  21  19  22
2014   8  10  15  14  11  17  14  13   6  18   7  20
2015   5   4  11  22  15   1   1
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

If there are no zeros for the last two months, the conversion seems to work fine.  If I replace the zeros in the last two months with NAs, I get a second different set of values for the time series.

Based on Alex's suggestion I tried:

```
 ts(x0.reg, start=c(2012,1), frequency=12)
     Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
2012  28   2   3  25  27  20  24  22  19  26  12  23
2013   9   6  16  18  18  15  23  19  14  21  19  22
2014   8  10  15  14  11  17  14  13   6  18   7  20
2015   5   4  11  22  15   1   1
```

It looks like the same (wrong) result.

Comment: It would be more helpful if you use `dput()` for the data instead of printing it out.

Comment: Also, I've had some problems in the past with`as.ts()` vs `ts()`. Not sure if that would help; but what about `ts(x0.reg, start= c(2012,1), frequency= 12)`?

Comment: Interestingly I get the same (wrong) result, see above.

Comment: OK, I think I have worked it out.  I need to ensure that zoo thinks the data is numeric when I initially create the zoo object, by using `x0.zoo <- zoo(as.numeric(x0[,2]), order.by=x0[,1])`.  Using str() on the various objects enabled me to see what the problem was.

Comment: you'd still need to take the date column out. TS objects are vectors with a date identifier. You shouldn't include both columns

Answer (score 0):

By using str(x0.zoo) and str(x0.reg) I was able to work out that the zoo object was not created with numeric data. Using:

```
x0.zoo <- zoo(as.numeric(x0[,2]), order.by=x0[,1])
```

to create the zoo object made everything work as expected, resulting in time-series data:

```
     Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
2012  88 103 120  74  83  65  72  68  64  80  53  70
2013  49  43  58  63  63  57  70  64  56  66  64  68
2014  48  51  57  56  52  60  56  54  43  63  47  65
2015  42  41  52  68  57   0   0
```